# Does the VB ErrorObject work with try/catch blocks or just onError/GoTo?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

When converting onError/GoTo statements from VB6 into VB.Net, I've been told to use try/catch statements instead. Most of the VB6 error blocks utilize Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject to provide the error code and description. For example:

```
 CombinePDF_ERROR:
        lErrorCode = Err
        strErrorSource = Err.Source
        strErrorDescription = Err.Description
        bInProcess = False
        strCombinePDFLastFile1 = strFile1
        strCombinePDFLastFile2 = strFile2
        ChDrive left$(strCurrentDir, 1)
        ChDir strCurrentDir
        Call CombinePDFUIUnload
        Err.Raise lErrorCode, strErrorSource, strErrorDescription
 End Sub
```

Does the Err (Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject) get its information from the onError/GoTo statements? lErrorCode, strErrorSource, strErrorDescription aren't given values prior to this. How do I replicate this functionality in a try/catch? Catch an exception and messageBox the message? First time using VB6 or VB.Net. Thank you for your time.

Comment: we cant see the code which might result in an error making this very, very broad.  [These guys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) know a lot about Try/Catch, start there

Comment: The VB 'Err' object and the pre-.NET error handling statements beginning with 'On Error' or 'Resume' live in their own little world which is not compatible with structured exception handling (VB won't even let you include both types within the same method). Avoid the legacy VB error handling and reproduce what you need with structured exception handling.

Comment: The [source for `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ErrObject`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/ErrObject.vb) gives some clues of the translations and how exceptions map to and from "classic" VB errors.

Answer (score 1):

That specific code in your question is basically like this Catch block below. The Err.Raise is equivalent to a Throw, and the Err object is roughly equivalent to an Exception object.

```
Catch ex
  bInProcess = False
  strCombinePDFLastFile1 = strFile1 
  strCombinePDFLastFile2 = strFile2
  ChDrive left$(strCurrentDir, 1)
  ChDir strCurrentDir 
  Call CombinePDFUIUnload
Throw ex
```

But that's just that one block. You need to check each VB6 error handler, work out what its doing, and work out the closest equivalent with Try Catch. You need to understand the VB6 On Error and the Err object, and also .Net Try...Catch and Exception object.

You are going to have a very hard time on this project if you don't know VB6 or VB.Net.